# How to set the CONNECTION_OPTIONS = 'ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly' for elastic queries on Azure SQL?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, database-replication

I am accessing the other database using elastic queries. The data source was created like this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE TheCompanyQueryDataSrc WITH (
    TYPE = RDBMS,
    --CONNECTION_OPTIONS = 'ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly',
    CREDENTIAL = ElasticDBQueryCred,
    LOCATION = 'thecompanysql.database.windows.net',
    DATABASE_NAME = 'TheCompanyProd'
);
```

To reduce the database load, the read-only replica was created and should be used. As far as I understand it, I should add the `CONNECTION_OPTIONS = 'ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly'` (commented out in the above code). However, I get only the `Incorrect syntax near 'CONNECTION_OPTIONS'`

Both databases (the one that sets the connection + external tables, and the other *to-be-read-only* are at the same server (thecompanysql.database.windows.net). Both are set the compatibility lever SQL Server 2019 (150).

What else should I set to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current&preserve-view=true&tabs=dedicated#syntax-1) Syntax doesn't support the option `CONNECTION_OPTIONS = 'ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly'`. We can't use that in the statements.

If you want achieve that readonly request, the way is that please use the user account which only has the readonly(db_reader) permission to login the external database.

For example:

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '<password>' ;

CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL SQL_Credential
WITH
  IDENTITY = '<username>' -- readonly user account,
  SECRET = '<password>' ;

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyElasticDBQueryDataSrc
WITH
  ( TYPE = RDBMS ,
    LOCATION = '<server_name>.database.windows.net' ,
    DATABASE_NAME = 'Customers' ,
    CREDENTIAL = SQL_Credential
  ) ;
```

Since the option is not supported, then we can't use it with elastic query. The only way to connect to the Azure SQL data with SSMS is like this:
[image]

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, reading the documentation, the syntax should be correct (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql). My reason for trying that is not to limit the access to read-only. The intention is to use the read-only replica of the database.

Comment: @pepr Please note that SQL server support it but Azure SQL doesn't. Select a product choose SQL Database you can find the difference.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense. Still, the intention actually is to redirect the query to the read-only replica of the Azure SQL database. I cannot find how to do that.

Comment: @pepr Since the option is not supported, then we can't connect to the replica with elastic query. Please see my update. If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.